# “Strange” C# property syntax

Tags: c#, properties, indexer

I just saw this in a c# project:

```
public char this[int index]
```

I consider myself new to C#; any one can help what it's meaning?

Comment: "I consider myself new to C# any one can help what it's mean in c++" Wait, what?

Comment: @BoltClock A C++ person saw this in C# ?

Comment: @Shark: That's what I thought too - but only after a double-take.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is an Indexer.

> Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like
>   arrays. Indexers resemble properties except that their accessors take
>   parameters.
>   An indexer provides array-like syntax. It allows a type to be accessed
>   the same way as an array. Properties such as indexers often access a
>   backing store. We often accept a parameter of int type and access a
>   backing store of array type.

Read it from http://www.dotnetperls.com/indexer

```
string s = "hello";
Console.WriteLine (s[0]); // 'h'
Console.WriteLine (s[3]); // 'l'
```

**Implementing an indexer**

To write an indexer, define a property called this, specifying the arguments in square
brackets. For instance:

```
class Sentence
{
   string[] words = "The quick brown fox".Split();
   public string this [int wordNum] // indexer
   {
      get { return words [wordNum]; }
      set { words [wordNum] = value; }
   }
}
```

Here’s how we could use this indexer:

```
Sentence s = new Sentence();
Console.WriteLine (s[3]); // fox
s[3] = "kangaroo";
Console.WriteLine (s[3]); // kangaroo
```

A type may declare multiple indexers, each with parameters of different types. An
indexer can also take more than one parameter:

```
public string this [int arg1, string arg2]
{
  get  { ... } set { ... }
}
```

Indexers internally compile to methods called `get_Item` and `set_Item`, as follows:

```
public string get_Item (int wordNum) {...}
public void set_Item (int wordNum, string value) {...}
```

The compiler chooses the name `Item` by default—you can actually change this by
decorating your indexer with the following attribute:

```
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IndexerName ("Blah")]
```

Answer (score 7):

this is called `indexer`.

- [Indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx)
- [C++ implementation of the C# Property and Indexer with Accessor-Modifiers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33293/C-implementation-of-the-C-Property-and-Indexer-wit)

Answer (score 7):

That's called an *indexer*. Read more about them [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx).