# What is the this[parameter] syntax for?

Tags: c#, methods, syntax, this

I've just come across this syntax for the first time (I'm using WPF but not sure if it's only for WPF)

```
public string this[string name]
{
   if(this.User == name)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

What are the advantages of using this over a standard method like below?

```
public string Validate(string name)
{
   if(this.User == name)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

I tried compiling `public string this(string name)` and that doesn't work so the `this` aspect is the key. But does this format achieve something that a standard method doesn't and is it only specific to WPF or is it a language implementation?

Comment: @SonerGönül - You're right, this is a duplicate (should've searched a bit more than I did!). I can't delete this so could mods please close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx):

> Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like arrays. Indexers resemble properties except that their accessors take parameters.

These are normally used in collection types - dictionaries, lists and arrays for example.

In the specific example you have given, a method appears to be more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you. What took you so long to answer?! :D Will accept when I can.

Answer (score 3):

It is called [`Indexer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx).

> Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like
>   arrays. Indexers resemble properties except that their accessors take
>   parameters.

An indexer provides *array-like* syntax. It allows a type to be accessed the same way as an array. Properties such as indexers often access a backing store.

You can read [“Strange” C# property syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138258/strange-c-sharp-property-syntax/14138282#14138282)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that was how they were implemented.

Answer (score 0):

this[] syntax is "Indexer". It's syntax sugar for forwarding private backed collection. It allows you use class like array, but incapsulate some logic before return data. For example, you can wrap Dictionary to return null for unexisted key instead of throwing exception.

Answer (score 0):

That allows you to use your class as you would do with an Array to access elements:

for ex instead of writing

> var element = myObject.GetElementAt(index);

you write

> var element = myObject[index];